# Where to put the if condition in shiny dashbord

Tags: r, shiny

This is a general question which is the better approach to put the if condition in the server part of the dashboard

1st option

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

df <-reactive({

    if else condition 

    return(df)
  })

output$table <- renderTable(df())

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server),launch.browser = TRUE)
```

2nd Option

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$table <- renderTable(if else condition) ## put the if condition direct inside render 

}

runApp(shinyApp(ui, server),launch.browser = TRUE)
```

No Code this is just for my knowledge

Want to know about the best approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1 is useful if you need `df()` in multiple places so that you don't have to repeat the `if else` everywhere. With this approach all your data manipulations are centralized in one place which is great for debugging and maintenance.

Option 2 is okay if you are using `df()` only once in some `render*` but such a scenario would only show up in very simple apps.

**Overall, Option 1 is better as it is more generalized and you would end up using that approach anyways as you start developing complex apps**.